# Transfer the IMail object to another form

Tags: c#

There is a function that receives letters:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
            ListViewItem list = new ListViewItem("Messages");
            using (imap = new Imap())
            {
                imap.ConnectSSL("imap.yandex.ru");
                imap.Login("----", "---");
                imap.SelectInbox();
                List<long> uids = imap.SearchFlag(Flag.All);
                IMail email;
                listView1.Items.Clear();
                foreach (long uid in uids)
                {
                    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
                    email = new MailBuilder().CreateFromEml(imap.GetMessageByUID(uid));                   
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(email.Subject);
                     listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
                }
            }
        }
```

Another form that I try to pass to the IMAIL objecto oher form:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {//тут надо пулучать выбранный UID

        //получим выделенный элемент
        int SelectedMessageIndex = listView1.FocusedItem.Index;
       IMail email2 = new MailBuilder().CreateFromEml(imap.GetMessageByUID(SelectedMessageIndex));
        MessageForm messageForm = new MessageForm(SelectedMessageIndex,email2); //нужно передать нужный email
        messageForm.ShowDialog();

    }
```

But I get the error:

> Access to the liquidated object is not possible.
>   Object name: "ClientBase".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `imap` variable is a class member. The problem lies with this:

```
using (imap = new Imap())
```

... in `button1_Click()`. When the `using()` code block ends, your `imap` object gets disposed. When you try using it again in `button2_Click()` it's already gone. You'll need to either not dispose the object or create a new imap object in `button2_Click()`.